# how should i fix this React hook useState error

Tags: reactjs

The error is "React Hook "useState" is called in function "textForm" that is neither a React function component nor a custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use""

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the section titled "Help others reproduce the problem". You may want to read the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the problem" as well.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Name your function as `useTextForm` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Custom hooks must be called as

> useTextForm()